# ErrorItemNotFound - The specified object was not found in the store

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

I'm doing an integration of my platform with the Office 365 Calendar through the Microsoft Graph API. As authentication I am using Admin Consent!

Sometimes when I try to update or delete an event from a user I get this error:

```
  ErrorItemNotFound - The specified object was not found in the store.
```

I have searched about it and I need help figuring this one out.

Comment: Did you find the fix? I have the same problem

Comment: Did we find any solution to this issue? I can also see that event exists in group but using graph explorer it return 404. If its a node sync issue then do we know what's the max time it will take to sync?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do the opposite, first verify the object exists an then remove. This due to the distributed nature of the platform changes are not propagated immediately to all nodes

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answ.
When i try to see if the event exist, the event is there , and if i try later it works!

Have you some suggestion how to avoid this when trying to updating a event?

Comment: Thanks Chistophe, in fact I would do quite the same and then wait a short while. Even I'm a fan of O365 can't say the nodes are populated as fast as we´d like it. Good luck!

Comment: BTW using PowerShell I just updated something very simple in my lab tenant (the primary SMTP address of an O365 group) and over a couple of minutes there were diferences between "Get-UnifiedGroup -Identity" output, the Exchange admin center, and the O365 admin center ... nothing we should worry that much about indeed :-)

Comment: Thanks for your help , is little strange indeed , how it work :/ will try to do a wait when this error happen! Is not the best solution but can not figuere a other one